# Android: Add own View to LinearLayour

Tags: android, view

I have created an own View:

```
    private class SampleView extends View {
```

and I want to "plant" this View into a LinearLayout which I created in an xml file.
How do I do that? Can someone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add your custom `View` like this:

```
<view
   class="test.project.app.Compass$SampleView"
   //... other attributes
/>
```

Your custom `View` class must be `public` and `static` for the above code to work.
Another option is to put the `SampleView` in its own file and simply use the code from the answers above.

Answer (score 3):

add in your layout file

```
<LinearLayout >

<com.yourpackagename.SampleView />

<LinearLayout>
```

**or**

```
LinearLayout lLayout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.linearlayout);
lLayout.addView(new SampleView());
```

Answer (score 2):

Just use the fully qualified name of your custom view class

```
<LinearLayout ...>
  <your.package.SampleView 
    android:layout_width=".."
    android:layout_height=".."
    ..
  >
  </your.package.SampleView >
  ..
</LinearLayout>
```

However, remove "private" from your class definition, and if it a nested class add **static**.

You can't use inner classes at this point

Comment: I tried this, but it gives me the exception:  java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{test.project.app/test.project.app.Compass}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #14: Error inflating class test.project.app.Compass.SampleView

Comment: i declare the SampleView in my Compass.java class

Comment: Please publish your current code and the full exception log. Take care of nested class, there MUST be static